# problem with trying to put 2 css transitions on a single html div container

Tags: html, css

so I'm studying website design in college, and in my assignment, we have to put 2 transitions on a single div container while the cursor hovers above it.

The transitions are the following:

the first transition will start after a delay of 1 second, will last 3 seconds and must be ease-in-out, during that transition, the corners of the border will now be square, the width of the border will double, the style of the border will become 3D and the color will be purple.

The second transition will start after a delay of 2 seconds, will last 3 seconds and must be linear,
during that transition, the background color of the div will become black, the color of the text that are in their basic color (that aren't affected by another css declaration) will become white and the font-weight of the text will become bolder.

The problem i have is that if i put 2 transition statement in my css declaration, on the second transition will start and the first one will just do it instantly, so how can i put 2 different transitions in one css declaration?

Here's my code:

```
/*J'ai adapté la taille du div via essai-erreurs, et j'ai trouvé qu'à 250px, la taille était juste suffisant.*/
.dv_ti{
    width: 250px;
    border: 6px solid #ED7D31;  
    background-color: #FFFF99;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: 1s border-radius 1s ease-in-out, border-width 1s ease-in-out, border-style 0.5s ease-in-out, border-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: 2s background-color 1s linear, color 1s linear, font-weight 1s linear;
}

.dv_ti:hover{
    border-width: 12px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-color: purple;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;

}
```

Yes the comments are in french since i'm in a french speaking college and live in a french speaking province, so if my explanation is kinda rough in english, i'm sorry it's not my first language unfortunately, and also i didn't put my whole code, cause it would have been a huge chunk, so I just put the 2 parts that are concerned.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine them both in one property and then set the delay and duration of each as you want:

```css
.dv_ti {
  width: 250px;
  border: 6px solid #ed7d31;
  background-color: #ffff99;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition:
  /* name | duration | easing function | delay */
    border-radius 1s ease-in-out 1s,
    border-width 1s ease-in-out 1s,
    border-style 0.5s ease-in-out 1s,
    border-color 0.5s ease-in-out 1s,
  /* Second transitioned delayed 2s */
    background-color 1s linear 2s,
    color 1s linear 2s,
    font-weight 1s linear 2s;
}

.dv_ti:hover {
  border-width: 12px;
  border-style: ridge;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: purple;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div class="dv_ti">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing 
</div>
```